# How do I match the rotation of a cube to a quad so it stays flat on it as I move it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

To keep it simple, I'm just trying to draw an arrow prefab along a quad that is at an angle. I need it to be flat against it (slightly raised) whatever position it's in.

What I'm doing right now is I've got a cube for the body of the arrow and a "triangle" prefab for the head. I click on the screen to get the "start position" (using a raycast hit point to make sure I'm over the my rotated quad below), then as I drag the mouse around it updates the "end position" vector 3. I simply calculate the distance between both points to see what "localScale.y" to expand it by, which works perfectly for the arrow length. For the head, I just attach it to the "end point", so it just follows the mouse.

**The problem I have is that it isn't staying "flat" against the quad**, which is rotated at X by 70 (in the inspector). And because of this, it rotates around length axis as I move and rotate the mouse in a circle.

Here my code:

```
 if (Physics.Raycast(mouseRay, out hit))
        {
            arrowEndPoint = hit.point;

            // Get rotation of Quad
            quadRotation = rotatedQuad.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x;
            var arrowBodyRotation = simpleArrowBody.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
            var arrowHeadRotation = simpleArrowHead.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;

            arrowBodyRotation.x = quadRotation;     // Doesn't seem to be affecting it
            arrowHeadRotation.x = quadRotation;

            // Follow arrow head to mouse
            simpleArrowHead.transform.position = arrowEndPoint;

            // Get distance between Start and End point
            arrowLength = Vector3.Distance(arrowStartPoint, arrowEndPoint);

            // Direction based on the start and end points
            var direction = (arrowEndPoint - arrowStartPoint).normalized;

            // Adjust scale and rotation of Body
            simpleArrowBody.transform.localScale = new Vector3(simpleArrowBody.transform.localScale.x, arrowLength, simpleArrowBody.transform.localScale.z);
            simpleArrowBody.transform.up = direction; 

            // Adjust rotation of Head
            simpleArrowHead.transform.up = direction;
            simpleArrowHead.transform.up = -rotatedQuad.transform.forward; // Didn't work
        }
```

Comment: Could you show us in your scene, how do you want to rotate arrow?

Comment: Could you just add the arrow as a child of the quad so that it moves together with it? It'd be the simpler solution if so.

Comment: Sven Viking  Unfortunately I can't do that as there are multiple items following that quad rotation all acting independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>   quadRotation = rotatedQuad.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x;
>   var arrowBodyRotation = simpleArrowBody.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
>   var arrowHeadRotation = simpleArrowHead.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
>
>   arrowBodyRotation.x = quadRotation;     // Doesn't seem to be affecting it
>   arrowHeadRotation.x = quadRotation;
> ```

of course this has no effect at all!

You are only assigning this to a local variable `Vector3` (which is a `struct` and thereby a **copied value**).

If you wanted to actually apply this back you would e.g. use

```
quadRotation = rotatedQuad.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x;
var arrowBodyRotation = simpleArrowBody.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
var arrowHeadRotation = simpleArrowHead.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;

arrowBodyRotation.x = quadRotation;
arrowHeadRotation.x = quadRotation;

simpleArrowBody.transform.rotation.eulerAngles = arrowBodyRotation;
simpleArrowHead.transform.rotation.eulerAngles = arrowHeadRotation;
```

---

**BUT** note that [`eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) are pretty unreliable for his!

Working with rotation directly is often quite tricky. So I usually prefer to wok with vectors simply because I understand them better ;)

What I would do is

- Rather design your arrow in a way that it is "normally" oriented. Meaning that it points into local **Z (forward)** direction and the one facing towards you is its local up direction.. Unity provides helper methods in this case.
- And then you can simply use [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) with your `direction` and as the up vector pass in the `-rotatedQuad.transform.forward`

Something like e.g.

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform rotatedQuad;
    public Transform simpleArrowHead;
    public Transform simpleArrowBody;

    private Vector3? arrowStartPoint;

    private void Update()
    {
        var mouseRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && Physics.Raycast(mouseRay, out var hit))
        {
            arrowStartPoint = hit.point;
        }
        else if (arrowStartPoint.HasValue && Input.GetMouseButton(0) && Physics.Raycast(mouseRay, out hit))
        {
            var arrowEndPoint = hit.point;

            // Get distance between Start and End point
            var delta = arrowEndPoint - arrowStartPoint.Value;
            var arrowLength = delta.magnitude;

            // Direction based on the start and end points
            var direction = delta.normalized;

            // Adjust position, scale and rotation of Body
            var scale = simpleArrowBody.localScale;
            scale.z = arrowLength;
            simpleArrowBody.localScale = scale;
            // make the forward point into the direction while maintaining the 
            // up vector aligned with the quad surface
            simpleArrowBody.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction, -rotatedQuad.forward);
            // place at center between start and end
            simpleArrowBody.position = arrowStartPoint.Value + delta / 2f;

            // Follow arrow head to mouse and adjust rotation of Head
            simpleArrowHead.position = arrowEndPoint;
            // make the forward point into the direction while maintaining the 
            // up vector aligned with the quad surface
            simpleArrowHead.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction, -rotatedQuad.forward);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's amazing! Thanks so much for your detailed answer. I used your second option. It worked perfectly once I changed it using the z scale instead. Also, I'm glad you showed how to adjust the start point using "delta". I had no idea how to adjust it so I just changed the origin by creating a custom "cube" in blender.